# How to convert a string with comma separated values into variables in php?

Tags: php

For instance, suppose I had 3 columns in my database: `column1, column2, column3`

And I had 3 variables with the same name as that of the columns:

```
$column1 = 'Column 1 value';
$column2 = 'Column 2 value';
$column3 = 'Column 3 value';
```

So if I appended a '`$`' sign to the column names in a foreach loop, I'll get the variable names.

```
$string = "column1, column2, column3";

function get_variable_names($string) {
    $array = explode(", ", $string); // Convert to array

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $array_values_with_dollar[] = '$'.$value;
    }
    $imploded = implode(", ", $array_values_with_dollar); // Convert to string again
    return $imploded;
}

$variable_string = get_variables($string);
```

Now, the value of `$variable_string` would be: `$column1, $column2, $column3`. (string).

Would it be possible to output the real value of the variables such that:

`$variable_string => Column 1 value, Column 1 value, Column 1 value`

[ without using [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call them like this:

```
echo ${'column1'};
```

So if you want to do a loop:

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    echo ${'column' . $i} . '<br>';
```

If you want it with a foreach, you can do it like this:

```
$string = 'column1, column2, column3';
$variables = explode(', ', $string);

foreach($variables as $variable)
    echo $$variable . '<br>';
```

### Result

```
Column 1 value
Column 2 value
Column 3 value
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: How to return add $$variable values to an array? eg.:
$name= '1 value'; $date= '2 value';  $email= '3 value'; 
$string = 'name, date, email';
$variables = explode(', ', $string);
$cesta = array();
array_push($cesta, $variables); 
$G_line = $cesta;
$G_line_string=implode("|", $G_line); // return 1 value|2 value|3 value ?????

Comment: @user3768564 Simply use `foreach ($variables as $variable) { array_push($cesta, $$variable); }`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$$` instead of `$`

```
$column1 = 'Column 1 value';
$column2 = 'Column 2 value';
$column3 = 'Column 3 value';

$string = "column1, column2, column3";
$array = explode(", ", $string);
foreach ($array as $elemnt){
    echo $$elemnt . "<br>";
}
exit;
```

outputs

```
Column 1 value
Column 2 value
Column 3 value
```

Answer (score 1):

i think , you may use this code

```
$column1 = 'Column 1 value';
$column2 = 'Column 2 value';
$column3 = 'Column 3 value';

$string = "column1, column2, column3";

function get_variable_names($string) {
    $array = explode(", ", $string);         
    return $array;
}

$variable_array = get_variable_names($string);



foreach($variable_array as $str){
    echo $$str.'<br/>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list to list the variables and explode on delimiter.

```
List($column1, $column2, $column3) = explode(", ", "column1, column2, column3");
```

https://3v4l.org/IMAoQ